# Link complement states in Chern Simons theory

Tags: conformal-field-theory, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory, wess-zumino-witten

I have been trying to understand how to get an explicit quantum state from a given link in Chern-Simons. Lets say the compact gauge group being SU(2) (this seems to be the most widely studied). I cannot however find a single paper/note where the entire calculation is done explicitly. That would include starting with a link, an explanation of the chosen representation, complete calculation of Wilson loop expectation values, association to the Hilbert space, and finally ending with the exact quantum state it corresponds to. Anything and everything else in between.

All I read everywhere is the theory. Just one example with complete details (not a single step/equation missing) would be infinitely more helpful. Is there any such reference where I might study from? Or even multiple references where I can find parts of each, but add up to be complete?